# Convert listbox to DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I am looking to change from a listbox to a DataGridView.

From the listbox, I can view the data and select items with view/download varbinary.

Can I do the same thing with DataGridView ?

Here is my code:

```
Dim sqlcon As New SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-U7KC2PG\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=kankon;Integrated Security=True")

Dim cmd As SqlCommand
Dim adapter As SqlDataAdapter
Dim ofd As New OpenFileDialog
Dim Dt As New DataTable


Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Try


        adapter = New SqlDataAdapter("select ID, Label + Extension as 'FileName', [Filesys] from TBL_FILES", sqlcon)

        adapter.Fill(Dt)

        Me.ListBox1.DataSource = Dt
        Me.ListBox1.DisplayMember = "FileName"

        Me.ListBox1.ValueMember = "ID"

        Me.Dt.Constraints.Add("Primary", Dt.Columns("ID"), True)

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

End Sub


Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Try
        Dim FileName As String = Me.ListBox1.Text
        Dim row As DataRow = Dt.Rows.Find(ListBox1.SelectedValue)
        Dim file_data() As Byte = CType(row(2), Byte())
        Dim fs As New FileStream(FileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write)

        fs.Write(file_data, 0, file_data.Length)
        Process.Start(FileName)
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub


Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Try


        ofd.Filter = "All File (*.*) |*.*"

        If ofd.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
            Label1.Text = ofd.FileName
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub


Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Try


        cmd = New SqlCommand("Insert into TBL_FILES (Label, Filesys,Extension) values (@Label, @Filesys, @Extension)", sqlcon)

        sqlcon.Open()

        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Label", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50)).Value = TextBox1.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Extension", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50)).Value = TextBox1.Text

        Dim fs As New FileStream(ofd.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)

        Dim br As New BinaryReader(fs)

        Dim file() As Byte = br.ReadBytes(br.BaseStream.Length)

        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("Filesys", SqlDbType.VarBinary)).Value = file

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        sqlcon.Close()

        MsgBox(" file saved ", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "info")

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Bind your `DataTable` to a `BindingSource` and then bind that to the `DataGridView`.  When the user selects a row, you can get the underlying `DataRowView` from the `Current` property of the `BindingSource`.  You could have done the same with the `ListBox`.

Comment: sorry am beginner coding could you help me with the new code my DataGridView  name is TBL_FILESDataGridView , and dataset is TBL_FILES thanks

Comment: Being a beginner doesn't mean wait for someone else to write code for you. It means research the appropriate topics to find information you can use. I've provided you with keywords you can use to do that research.  Now you need to do it.

Comment: Never use an empty try-catch.  You always want to know what the exception is so you can fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Based off of the comment and your response, it looks like you have chosen to try and use a datagridview... Here is some helpful code to use these.

Notes: I'm going to assume you're using a simple sqlCommand to get your data, if not ignore the "com" part of this as I'm only including it to show you the flow of how this works. Note: Clearing a dataset before repeated use is a good idea to be sure you've purged old data.

You may also want to consider renaming your objects to something more appropriate such as "dsTblFiles" and "gvTblFiles".

```vbnet
Dim adapter as New SqlDataAdapter()

TBL_FILES.Clear()
adapter.SelectCommand = com
adapter.Fill(TBL_FILES)

TBL_FILESDataGridView.DataSource = TBL_FILES.Tables(0)
TBL_FILESDataGridView.DataBind()

adapter = Nothing
```

Comment: A `DataGridView` has no `DataBind` method.

Comment: i was try but not working , am gonna add all code soon

Comment: the file open it , but am gitting error when open it  ( System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index ))  - Private Sub TBL_FILESDataGridView_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles TBL_FILESDataGridView.CellContentClick

        adapter.Fill(Dt)

        TBL_FILESDataGridView.DataSource = TBL_FILESBindingSource.ToString
        TBL_FILESDataGridView.Rows(3).Cells(0).Value.ToString()
     adapter = Nothing
    End Sub